# Importing a google protocol buffer generated package

Tags: go, import, package

I generated a .go file from a .proto file. I added the .go file generated by GPB underneath my local project directory in mdproto directory. My package is called mdproto.go.

In go, I say

```
package main

import (
    "./mdproto"
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)
... more go stufff
```

But when I try to run it, the output is as below. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
[idf@node1 9664255]$sudo go run gistfile1.go 
# command-line-arguments
./gistfile1.go:4: imported and not used: "_/home/idf/Documents/go/9664255/mdproto" as MarketData
```

EDIT: This fixes it:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    "./mdproto"
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

const (
    srvAddr         = "239.0.0.222:345"
    maxDatagramSize = 8192
)

func main() {
    md :=  &MarketData.MD {
            Firm: int64(1),
            Id  : int64(1),            
            Bid : float64(17),
            Ask : float64(18),            
            }
    data, err := proto.Marshal(md)

    log.Println(data, err)

    go ping(srvAddr)
    serveMulticastUDP(srvAddr, msgHandler)
}

etc...
```

Comment: I noticed u have `Documents` in the error message. Just a guess, but what is your $GOPATH? And does all of your go code reside in `$GOPATH/src/` somewhere?  Also, use the full import path for the protobuf package, no relative paths.

Comment: "imported and not used" basically says it all, doesn't it?

Comment: @Markus, But why is that and error? My program runs otherwise if I remove that import. In other words, it is being treated as an error, not a warning.

Comment: @educan, why would that matter. It is clearly finding the package.

Comment: Looks like golang treats unused variables as errors. As soon as I patched it all, it works. See edit above for solution

Comment: @Ivan Since the Go compiler says so. The reason is that unnecessary imports just bloat the compiled binary.